# Error Importing CRM4.0 Organisation in CRM 2011...Why does it fail??...

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

CRM 2011 Server and SQL Server 2008 R2 (running in same machine)...Installed CRM 2011 with Reporting extensions. When I try to import process the CRM 4.0 database through CRM 2011 Deployment Manager,it fails. I map all users and validation screen passes with warnings and without errors ...Why is it failing can someone point me into a right direction looking at the logs.

It doesn't take long before it fails...|I copied most frequent lines of the log before it failed...

Your help is much appreciated...

> Info| Upgrading the views in the MSCRM database
>
> Info| CrmAction execution time; UpgradeDatabaseAction;
>   00:21:23.6584839
>
> | Error| Installer Complete: OrganizationUpgrader - Error encountered
>
> |Error| Exception occured during
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationUpgrader:
>
> Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction failed.
>   InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 
>   Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: SqlException: Invalid column name
>   'New_name'. Invalid column name 'New_Details'. Invalid column name
>   'New_Test'., View Script: if exists (select * from sysobjects where
>   name =  'New_action' and xtype = 'V') begin
>       drop view [New_action] end go
>
> .......... ..........
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name

Could anyone please help me with this problem

Thanks in Advance

Prajosh

Comment: What Update Rollup are you on for MSCRM? Might be worth patching it up and retrying in the first instance. The latest version is Update Rollup 8 [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600644)

Comment: Is there any chance that the CRM database has been changed at any point directly in SQL server (rather than via the CRM ui)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution - I added the missing columns manually

Comment: Sounds like they must have been removed manually at some point in the past...?